# Open set in a metric space is union of closed balls?

Tags: metric-spaces

We know that every open set $A$ is in a metric space $(X,d)$ is the countable union of closed sets, and every open set $A$ is in a Euclid space $R^n$ is the countable union of closed balls.

My question is, in what spaces, every open set is the countable union of closed balls.

If every open set $A$ is in a metric space $(X,d)$ is the countable union of closed balls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take the set $X=\mathbb R\times \mathbb [0,1]$ with metric
$$d\bigl((x,y),(u,v)\bigr)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\ne u\\|y-v|&\text{if }x=u\end{cases} $$
Then the set $$A=\mathbb R\times (0,1)=\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb R}B\bigl((x,\tfrac12),\tfrac12\bigr)$$ is open, but not the countable union of closed balls (nor is it the countable union of open balls).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every countable open-ball-covering can be made into a countable closed-ball-covering.

Take a countable number of open balls that cover $A$. Each ball $B_i$ has a center $a_i$ and a radius $r_i$. Now for each $i$ look at the set of closed balls $\overline{B}_{i,n}$ centered at $a_i$ with radius $(1-1/n)r_i$ for $n \in \Bbb N$.

The full collection of these $\overline{B}_{i,n}$ is still countable, and cover exactly the same points as the original $B_i$-balls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in a measure-theoretic setting, then, up to a subset of measure zero, yes! Start with one closed ball in your set. This exists since you can find an open ball, by definition of openness, and then the closed ball of radius equal to 90% of the former radius is contained in your set. Complement of this ball is open, so, find another ball, and just keep adding balls!